# QBO Task user-defined fields in Excel

Tags: excel, sqlxml, qbo3

I am using pulling existing Task data into an Excel spreadsheet to use with a Score. I have an Excel named range executing `?=ImportForm/ListDeep?TargetObject=Loan&TargetObjectID={LoanID}`.

My tasks include several user-defined fields, but the data renders in Excel lumps them together in a single column called `XmlData`.  How can I use these values in Excel formulas?

Answer (score 0):

The `ImportForm/ExecuteFlat` method will normalize user-defined fields (that that, elements stored in `ImportForm.XmlData`.  `ExecuteFlat` requires an `Operation` parameter, which it will execute before normalizing the results.

For your example, call:

```
?=ImportForm/ExecuteFlat?Operation=ListDeep&TargetObject=Loan&TargetObjectID={LoanID}
```

More generically, assume that `ImportForm/Search?ID=1` returns:

```xml
<ImportFormItem>
  <ImportFormID>1</ImportFormID>
  ...
  <XmlData>
    <ImportFormXml>
      <Foo>Bar</Foo>
      <Hello>World</Hello>
    </ImportFormXml>
  </XmlData>
</ImportFormItem>
```

Calling `ImportForm/ExecuteFlat?Operation=Search?ID=1` would return:

```xml
<ImportFormItem>
  <ImportFormID>1</ImportFormID>
  ...
  <Foo>Bar</Foo>
  <Hello>World</Hello>
</ImportFormItem>
```